# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error and array(0){}

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my pdo script, I was querying my database to give me all the users in my database in my local machine but all I see is "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error"

Here is my script;

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
require_once('connect.php');

try{

$username='charlyo';
$con=$connect->query('select * from users where username=:username');
var_dump($con->fetchAll());
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();

}

 ?>
```

and while trouble-shooting it I tried to use prepared statements. I now get "array(0){}" without returning any arrays while I used fetchAll method.

Here is the second script of prepared statement:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
require_once('connect.php');

try{

$username='charlyo';
$con=$connect->prepare('select * from users where username=:username');
$con->bindParam(':username',$username);
$con->execute();
var_dump($con->fetchAll());
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();

}

 ?>
```

Comment: `query` doesn't take placeholders, you also need to bind with placeholders.

Comment: You get the error from both scripts or just the first?

Comment: use `prepare` in the first query. Do the same thing you did in the second query for the first query

Comment: @chris85 first "General error" was from first script with query statement while the empty "array(0){}" was in the second script which i used prepared statement

Comment: Separate your `use charles;` statement, into a separate `$connect->query('use charles;')` then follow it with your `$connect->prepare()`; statement. Prepared statements can not utilize the `use` in the same statement

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for the correction @halfer, will apply it

Answer (score 2):

You should also post the contents of the file `connect.php`, so we can be sure of how you are instantiating the PDO object (make sure to remove the passwords).

Stacked queries (multiples queries separated by a `;`) are not supported by default in PDO, the emulation mode has to be enabled (`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`) but it's not really needed in your case.

In order to make your second example work, you should just remove the `use charles;` part and make sure to pass `dbname=charles` in the DSN that you are providing to PDO's constructor.

Comment: i have removed "use charles" from my query and i have changed the dbname=charles but nothing is changed, its still showing "array(0){},what else should i do" it is the second example that is troubling me now, that is the prepared stsatement. i have resolved the general error of the query statement i  the first example.

Comment: @charlyo: make sure that you have at least one record with a username being `charlyo`. I tried the second example at home before writing this comment and it's working as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I do have username charlyo in my database, don't understand what's happening, any more help plz, I really need it

Comment: Please add the contents of the file `connect.php` ; don't forget to strip any sensitive detail.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `use charles;` from query. I am not sure why you have used it but take it off from query and check.

Comment: Thanks @swapgs, it just worked, thanks a lot brother